# MSBuild: Passing multiple parameters to powershell not working as expected

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm calling a PowerShell script from a MSBuild target using this code:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <enabler/>
</PropertyGroup>    
<Target Name="testTarget">
    <CreateItem Include="LogsGeneratorScript.ps1">
        <Output ItemName="LogsGenerator" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Enabling Include="$(enabler)" />
    </ItemGroup> 

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' "> 
  %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted  -command "&amp; {  &amp;'%(LogsGenerator.Fullpath)'  '$(MSBuildProjectName)' '%(Enabling.Identity)'} "
        </PowerShellExe>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe)" />
</Target>
```

The problem I'm having is that `%(Enabling.Identity)` is causing `%(LogsGenerator.Fullpath)` to be passed as blank so I can see that when PowerShell is called the whole thing looks like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "& { &'' 'MyTestProject' 'true'} "
```

I was expecting this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "& { &'LogsGeneratorScript.ps1' 'MyTestProject' 'true'} "
```

Note that if I remove the last parameter `%(Enabling.Identity)` then the first percentage symbol property is correctly resolved:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "& { &'LogsGeneratorScript.ps1' 'MyTestProject'} "
```

Can someone suggest a way so that I can pass both of the percentage symbol parameters to PowerShell?

Comment: Can you show us more context, including the item definitions? I suspect the issue is more with how you are using MSBuild transforms than powershell.

Comment: @mikez I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be that MSBuild is iterating over the two ItemGroups independently, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giuliov/archive/2010/04/30/gotcha-msbuild-nested-loops-double-batching.aspx); the entirety of the first ItemGroup (ignoring the second), and then the entirety of the second ItemGroup (ignoring the first).

This is why you are seeing `%(LogsGenerator.Fullpath)` blank; it is busy iterating over `%(Enabling.Identity)`.

*I suspect that your PowerShell command will be called twice - once as you have described, and once with `%(LogsGenerator.Fullpath)` set and `%(Enabling.Identity)` blank.*

So, you need to decide how you want to combine these groups. There is an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786301/double-loop-in-msbuild) on how to iterate over the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two ItemGroups.

Alternatively, can't you avoid this entirely by using a [condition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) in there somewhere instead of turning `enabler` into an ItemGroup?